# typedef as base class not looked up in nested-name-specifier

Tags: c++, standards

I am a bit baffled as to why I need to specify my namespace in the following code when accessing the base class member.

After reading the standard, my understanding is that the qualified name I use after the `.` operator should look the nested-name-specifier left of `::` in the `Derived` class scope. 
Why doesn't it find `BaseTypeDef` but finds `Base` ?

Thanks

(I am getting the same behaviour on GCC 4.4.7 and GCC 4.9.2.)

```
namespace ns {
  struct Base {
    int a;
  };
  typedef Base BaseTypeDef;
  struct Derived : BaseTypeDef { };
}

int main()
{
  ns::Derived d;
  d.ns::BaseTypeDef::a = 0; // ok
  d.Base::a = 0;            // ok
  d.BaseTypeDef::a = 0;     // error: use of undeclared identifier 'BaseTypeDef'
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Base` is the *injected-class-name*. `BaseTypedef` isn't a member of the class in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: I assume the base class in your real code is actually a little more complicated (like a template)? Because otherwise I don't see a use-case for the type-alias.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks, didn't know about `injected-class-name` !